# Python - Parsing DAX expressions and identifying tables and fields

Tags: python, parsing, dax

I have a number of DAX expressions which references fields and tables.  The fields and tables have been translated into a foreign language and we would like to replace the names in the expressions with the translated version.

Is there a way to parse the DAX expression using Python to identify what is a field and what is a table etc?

Comment: If you understand the DAX syntax it should be fairly easy to parse in python using  [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp). Have you tried this?

Comment: If you just need to know for one single dax query you can paste it here and we can tell.